# Xamarin Forms data binding from xaml

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have an `<Entry>` in xaml, and I want to get that value the user types.

```
<Entry x:name="enteredInput>
```

The file with that `<Entry>` is in startingPage.xaml with a code behind class startingPage.xaml.cs.

Then I would like to transfer that value in the `<Label>` element of a different xaml, MainPage.xaml.

Comment: in your code behind, just pass the value of enteredInput.Text to your 2nd page and assign it to a Label

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your second page, add another constructor with string parameter.
For ex, If your page name is StartingPage.xaml, then add another constructor like below. Inside, assign the incoming value to your label.

```
public StartingPage(string entryTextFromStartingPage)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblEntryTextDisplay.Text = entryTextFromStartingPage;
    }
```

From the StartingPage.xaml.cs, add the below code in a button click or any event that you are calling the Main page,

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage(enteredInput.Text);
```

Comment: Thank you this works. It's one of those this that makes you go duh...I should of though about overloading the constructor. Do you think it would be more maintainable using the binding class, if you were to bind more values?

Comment: One more alternative is using Singleton pattern for assigning and accessing global  variables. You can access in code behind as well as viewmodel classes. But you have to clear them once you have used it. Sample below,

Comment: public sealed class SingletonGlobal   {
        private static SingletonGlobal instance = null;
        private static readonly object padlock = new object();

        public static SingletonGlobal Instance
        {
            get
            {
                lock (padlock)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new ApplicationCache();
                    }
                    return instance;
                }
            }
        }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

    }